# how to validate hour using express-validator npm

Tags: node.js, regex, express, express-validator

i'm trying to use a `express-validator` to validate a hour. I sent this json:

```
{
  "hour" : "10:30",
  "day":"monday"
}
```

in the following code:

```
var regex = new RegExp('/^(10|11|12|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/');
var hour = req.body.hour;

req.check('hour',"error to add hour").matches(regex);
var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){  
    res.status(400).send(errors);       
} else {
    res.status(200).json({hour:'hour ok'});
}
```

the program throws me the following error:

```
[
  {
    "param": "hour",
    "msg": "error to add hour",
    "value": "10:30"
  }
]
```

I think my error is in the validation of the regex. should send me `{hour:'hour ok'}`... please, help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it works better if you use

```
new RegExp(/^(10|11|12|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/);
```

or

```
new RegExp('^(10|11|12|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]$');
```

If you use a string as an argument to the regexp constructor you have to skip the slashes at the beginning and end of the string.